# How to replace the nth space before a string on each line in a file using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to replace the space before the surname on each line of a file with a comma using sed.

Example Source:

```
George W Heong§New York§USA
Elizabeth Black§Sheffield, Yorkshire§England
Lucy Jones§Cardiff§Wales
James G K Shackleton§Dallas, Texas§USA
Carl Seddon§Canberra,Australia
```

Example Ouput:

```
George W,Heong§New York§USA
Elizabeth,Black§Sheffield, Yorkshire§England
Lucy,Jones§Cardiff§Wales
James G K,Shackleton§Dallas, Texas§USA
Carl,Seddon§Canberra,Australia
```

I think I've worked out a method to obtain the index of the relevant space as follows:

```
int idx$ = str.indexOf("§");
int nthSpace = str.lastIndexOf(" ", idx$);
```

but I haven't been able to work out how to replace the nth instance with the variable nthSpace. This is what have got so far:

```
sed "s/$nthSpace" "/,/" datain.txt > dataout.txt
```

Any asistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you'll never have people with multiple surnames? Especially if you're targeting Great Britain?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Double barrelled surnames are typically separated by a `-`, so it is unlikely that it would cause a problem.

Comment: @123: There are millions of counterexamples. For example, in Spain, most people have two surnames (one paternal, one maternal name), separated by spaces. Apart from that, I can think of Helena Bonham Carter, Sacha Baron Cohen, Hillary Rodham Clinton, ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name

Comment: `in Spain`, well you said Britain originally, and yes there are exceptions but typically i have only seen the hyphen used for non celebrities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed :

```
sed 's/ \([^ ]*§\)/,\1/' sourcefile
```

The pattern looks for the first occurence of :

- a space
- followed by any non-space char
- followed by §

The name is captured in a group that is used in the substitution to be prefixed with a `,`

**UPDATE :**

To prevent strings as `name §` to be matched, you can preprocess the first substitution with `s/ +§/§/`. The final command will be :

```
sed 's/ +§/§/;s/ \([^ ]*§\)/,\1/' sourcefile
```

As noticed in question comments, multipart surnames (separated with spaces) will be split if not rewritten manually.

Comment: sed 's/ \([^ ]*§\)/,\1/' datasrc.txt > dataout.txt

Comment: but the command appeared to stall generating a blank dataout.txt file. The command had to be aborted. If I replace the single quotes with double quotes the command completes but the dataout.txt file output is identical to datasrc.txt. Does the command need to be altered to run on a Mac?

Comment: @ridgedale I'm not familiar with Mac. Maybe an encoding issue with the `§` char. Some details at : https://blog.lnx.cx/2013/09/24/mac-os-x-sed-and-strange-document-encoding/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I replaced all the instances of § with | and tried the following command:

Comment: sed 's/ ([^ ]*|)/,\1/' datasrc.txt > dataout.txt

Comment: sed: 1: "s/ ([^ ]*|)/,\1/": \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: You should escape the parentheses as in my answer by adding a slash before  : `\(` and `\)`

Comment: sed 's/ \([^ ]*|\)/,\1/' datasrc.txt > dataout.txt

Comment: That worked a treat. Thank you for your assistance. :)

Comment: Glad to help you. You can validate the answer if it's ok for you.

Comment: ++, but due to use of `*` this will also match a space directly followed by `§`; replacing `*` with `\{1,\}` would fix that (in a POSIX-compliant manner; _GNU_ `sed` would also support `\+`).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, i updated my answer. Strangely replacing `*` with `\{1,\}` (or `+` in ERE mode) did not work for me.

Comment: @Kenavoz: Hmm.. seems to work for me: `sed 's/ \([^ ]\{1,\}§\)/,\1/' <<<'name §'` yields `name<space>§`, as it should (no match). And, conversely, it still matches when it should: `sed 's/ \([^ ]\{1,\}§\)/,\1/' <<<'first last§'` yields `first,last§`.

Comment: Sure, but `sed 's/ \([^ ]\{1,\}§\)/,\1/' <<<'George W Heong §'
` outputs `George W Heong §`

Answer (score 1):

With `gensub`, available in GNU `awk`, you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="§"} {$1=gensub(/[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/, ",\\1", 1, $1)} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
George W,Heong§New York§USA
Elizabeth,Black§Sheffield, Yorkshire§England
Lucy,Jones§Cardiff§Wales
James G K,Shackleton§Dallas, Texas§USA
Carl,Seddon§Canberra,Australia
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the awk command fails with the error: awk: calling undefined function gensub
 input record number 1, file datasrc.txt
 source line number 1

Comment: I am using OSX, btw.

Comment: Hi anubhava, after some faffing around removing macports and running brew install gawk, I got gawk running on OSX 10.6.8. :)

Comment: The plain awk command as provided above failed with: awk: calling undefined function gensub
 input record number 1, file datasrc.txt
 source line number 1

Comment: gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="§"} {$1=gensub(/[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/, ",\\1", "1", $1)} 1' datasrc.txt > dataout.txt

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. :)

Comment: That's right as I mentioned and answer and commented earlier that it needs `gnu-awk` command since `gensub` is gnu extension